# How to package an ASP.NET application to prevent customers from modifying it?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a tool or some general approach to packaging all the files of an ASP.NET application into binary form to prevent modification once its deployed?  I am thinking there would be a set of signed binaries and a config file for settings that we allow the customer to modify.  Has anyone attempted this, is it even possible?

I would pay a reasonable amount for a slick commercial product that did this with minimal hassle.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, from the answers I can see that I wasn't clear.  I meant literally packaging ALL files, not just the code files.  This means aspx, scripts, images etc.  I'm not trying to prevent reverse engineering... this is a supportability issue, i.e. to avoid dealing with problems brought about by customer messing with the files.

Comment: You can prevent the customer from modifying it _easily_, but you can't prevent them from modifying it _with difficulty_.

Answer (score 6):

If you made a web application project than you can compile your code into a single dll file. You can find it in the bin folder.

Comment: This is what I would do in most situations. For bare bones deployment: On the Build menu, you can just tell it to Publish your web app somewhere and then deploy that. It won't include any code files -- just the bare essentials required to run.

Answer (score 2):

Just use aspnet_compiler.exe to precomple everything and then use aspnet_merge.exe to roll up all of the compiled assemblies into a single assembly.  You can use an obfuscation tool like DotFuscator if you want to make it more difficult to reverse-engineer.  Visual Studio pro and up include a "lite" edition of Dotfuscator that you can use for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your codebehind files will be compiled in a single dll as ZippyV already mentioned. The aspx files will get deployed normally on the webserver.

But still, your dll files can be disassembled quite easily. So to be sure you have to use an obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ALL files including the aspx you could also consider ngen.  It precompiles everything into a dll so you can't even get at the aspx pages.

Although, ngen was designed to get rid of the JIT compiling feature of the framework and is definitely not a generally recommended approach but it may work in your case well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [Dotfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator) your customer won't be able to modify it nor reverse-engineer it :)

Answer (score 0):

From VS2008 select the menu option "Tools" and then "Dotfuscator Community Edition".  You will have a "Learn More" link after it starts up.

I also sign mine using SN.exe to make it have a strong name.  Given all this, I think it is complicated enough to figure out a system if you are given the source code and help.... so I don't worry about it anymore.